# Form entry is changing the values in my Lookup table

Tags: ms-access

So, I I have two tables 1. Main table 2. Status table.
I want too, in a form, have the user select the status from the status table and it populate to the main table.
I created a query bring in the status table and create a Option 3 Join.
In the form I created the combo box pulling the list from the statusTBL this updates the main table with the ID (Auto#) the query with the value, and the report with the value. All good right, well no what is happening is it is randomly changing the data in the Status table to numbers. So where I once had "Started" it changed the value to a number "13"[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y2AOb.png).

Comment: I suspect you have combobox bound to wrong field. Bind form to just Main table, don't include Status table in form RecordSource.

Comment: Are you sure data is going into Main table?

Comment: https://www.fmsinc.com/microsoftaccess/forms/combo-boxes/cascading.html